# Is there a formal definition of a loop (in stability context)?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, feedback, loop-gain

[The circuit](http://fox.ece.ufl.edu/Multiple-Loop_Feedback.html) below with multiple feedback loops is taken from this page. 
The page considers only two loops in order to calculate the overall loop gain T. 
Is that enough?
Doesn't it have 4 loops instead? 
Is there a formal definition of a feedback loop?
Is it possible to simply consider a mesh in any electronic circuit and say that it is a feedback loop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding the first schematic: loop T3 is incorrect as the signal flow through R4 is from right (output of opamp) to left (input of opamp). So T3 should no go through R4 but through the opamp making it the same as T4.

Comment: Regarding the second picture: these are **current loops** and not **signal loops**, the two are unrelated. You only confuse yourself by relating those two types of loops so **don't**.

Comment: "*Is there a formal definition of a feedback loop?*" -- Have you tried to see what the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback) has to say about it?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I know the loop in the second picture is different but I want to know a definition to distinguish them from the first one. In the second picture, I just took it from some page but if you look at the top loop, if you break the loop at one point and insert a voltage source, there is a feedback signal. How does that different from the first picture? The only different thing I can see is that the first loop contains an active device. However, I haven't seen a formal definition for a feedback loop and wonder if an active device is necessary.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen how would you differentiate the loops in the first and second pictures (the top right loop in the second picture) then?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie for the second image, I took it from the internet just to show the loop. It is confusing but I don't actually talking about the current loop, just to show it as a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback is an active criterium by which a quantity from the output is taken and fed back at the input, such that the output is dependent on both the input and the output. Think of it as an implicit operation with \$V_o=f(V_i,V_o)\$, not just \$V_i\$.

As a simple example, think of the basic inverting opamp with its transfer function \$V_o=-(R_2/R_1)V_i\$, which is a deceivingly simple formula hiding the fact that what really happens in there is a sum of two quantities, the input and the output, *both* contributing to the output (that's an equation in two variables):

$$\dfrac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_i+\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_o=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad \dfrac{V_o}{V_i}=-\dfrac{R_2}{R_1}$$

In your 2nd picture there is feedback due to the currents involved, and this is something that can easily be seen by removing or changing the topology, which would lead to a different output. But while in both cases the outputs will be different, in the 2nd case there will never be any stability issues. The output is not dependent on that current feedback, i.e. the functionalilty of the circuit does not depend on the output.

Comment: The current loops in the second  picture is misleading but I actually tried to show the loops instead of the currents themselves. What do you mean by this `and this is something that can easily be seen by removing or changing the topology`?

Comment: @anhnha E.g. if you remove the 10 Ohm resistor you've changed the topology, and the current loops with it. Compare that with removing `R2` in the inverting opamp. That 10 Ohm is part of a passive network that can be simplified to a Thevenin or Norton case, easily, gving the same output. `R2`, OTOH, is part of an *active feedback*, and the circuit depends on it.

Comment: you can consider the 10 ohms resistor as a feedback component then it would be same. 
The only thing that is different I can see is the second one doesn't have active devices.

Comment: @anhnha Can you make a Norton or Thevenin equivalent out of that opamp? The simple fact that you can't while you can in the 2nd case should tell you how important is that 10 Ohm for the rest of the circuit. It's no different than your other question, where you think you have a feedback system simply because you used a block diagram, when, in fact, it's just a mathematical formula.

Comment: you can make Norton or Thevenin for the opamp output.

Comment: @anhnha Will that have the same \$V_o=f(V_i,V_o)\$, or simply \$V_o=K\cdot V_i\$?

Comment: Are they same? You can reduce the first one to the second one.

Comment: @anhnha Obviously not. The 2nd one has no \$V_o\$ in the right hand side.

Comment: But they're ultimately the same. You can convert one to the other.

Comment: @anhnha I don't understand, are you deliberately ignoring both your logic and what is already said? I'll give one last try: case 1 is \$V_o=f(V_i,K)\$ and case 2 is \$V_o=f(V_i,V_o)\$. For case 1 varying \$V_i\$ with \$f(V_i,K=\mathrm{constant})\$ results in a changing \$V_o\$. For case 2 varying \$V_i\$ with \$f(V_i,V_o=\mathrm{constant})\$ results in an impossibility since \$V_o\$ must change. Please re-read my answer (and the other answers to your other questions) without discarding information. Right in the beginning I say: "*feedback is an* **active** *criterium*" (in terms of stability).

Comment: Well, I didn't ignore what you said. You assumed `Vo=f(Vi,K)` for no feedback loop and `Vo=f(Vi,Vo)` in the circuit with feedback loop. However, I think they're same because `Vo=f(Vi,Vo)` you can move `Vo` to one side and got the function of `Vi` only. So you would get the same thing? Let me send this example. there is two feedback loops. 
https://ibb.co/2MsPvWs